# Redux-Form 6.8.0 remote submit with custom flag

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am wondering how to pass custom flag into redux-form `onSubmit` function. My scenario is that I have a 2 save buttons (both invoke a different API request) outside the redux form so I use remote submit approach.

Form Component:

```js
function handleFormSubmit(data) {
  // I need to distinguish here which button was clicked
}

class FormComponent extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        ...
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
})(reduxForm({
  form: 'MyForm',
  onSubmit: handleFormSubmit,
})(FormComponent));
```

Bar component with 2 buttons:

```js
import React from 'react';

class BarComponent extends React.Component {
  props: Props;


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onChange={this.props.submit('MyForm')}>Save</button>
        <button onChange={this.props.submit('MyForm')}>Save as new version</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  submit
})(BarComponent);
```

Any ideas how to know in `handleFormSubmit` which button was clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap each of those buttons in a `reduxForm` with the same `name` as your main form and implement the `onSubmit` logic differently for both. Even better, you can just abstract the thing out nicely:

```
// component code (take with a grain on pseudo-code salt)
export class SubmitButton extends Component {

  render() {
    const { children, handleSubmit } = this.props

    return (
      <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
        <button type="submit">{ children }</button>
      </form>
    )
  }

}

@reduxForm()
export default SubmitButtonContainer extends SubmitButton {}
```

The example above is basically an abstracted out button that will submit a `redux-form` form as long as you provide it with the form name and an `onSubmit` function. You should also be able to provide it with [any other `props` that `reduxForm` eats](http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/). If you need loading indication etc, you can just use [the props that come with wrapping a component with `reduxForm`](http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/docs/api/Props.md/).

Then you can use it for example like below to implement custom submit logic tied to different buttons:

```
// usage code (again more pseudo-code salts with this one)
import React from 'react';
import SubmitButton from 'path/to/SubmitButton'

class BarComponent extends React.Component {
  props: Props;

  onSave() {
    // do the regular save logic here
  }

  onSaveAsNewVersion() {
    // do the other save logic here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SubmitButton form="MyFormName" onSubmit={ this.onSave }>Save</button>
        <SubmitButton form="MyFormName" onSubmit={ this.onSaveAsNewVersion }>Save as new version</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  submit
})(BarComponent);
```

Both of the examples above should be treated as pseudocode, I don't guarantee they will work out of the box. The principle does work, I've implemented it a couple of times already.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @jakee. Actually I have known about approach you described but I've thought there is another way how to solve it, like somehow pass custom object to `submit` redux-form action creator and then obtain it in `onSubmit` handler set in main form component. Nevermind I'll go with your solution for now.